# User rights somehow not working properly on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-permissions

Somehow ubunut 16.04 does not allow me to write to a folder, despite the fact that the user is in the group that has write privileges:

```
$ ll
drwxrwxr-x 6 root grafana 4096 Nov 30 17:47 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root    4096 Jan  8 15:20 ../
drwxrwxr-x 2 root grafana 4096 Nov 30 17:47 plugins/

touch test
touch: cannot touch 'test': Permission denied

groups myuser
myuser : users sudo grafana
```

Shouldn't that user be able to write to the directory?

Comment: What are the permissions of the folder that you are trying to create the file in?

Comment: drwxrwxr-x   6 root grafana  4096 Nov 30 17:47 provisioning/ I added the user to the group grafana recently. Do I need to do something else despite of adding him to the group?

Comment: try logging out and the logging in again